# Merging DataGridView cell in Winforms after adding a new row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, merge

I am creating a WinForms application in visual studio 2017,

I have a dataGridView created with row data like the following:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| V |      Data 1      | Data 1 Quantity | Data 1 Details |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

After this data is created, the user enter some data to a textbox and submits.

then the software adds a new row to the dataGridView, the Table becomes as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| V |      Data 1      | Data 1 Quantity   | Data 1 Details   |
---------------------------------------------------------------
| V |      Data 1      | Data 1.A Quantity | Data 1.A Details |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I would like to have since V and Data 1 are the same, that the software merges both cells to become something like this.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| V   |      Data 1      | Data 1 Quantity   | Data 1 Details   |
                         ---------------------------------------- 
|     |                    Data 1.A Quantity | Data 1.A Details |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any way that I can merge these cells? I have tried in many ways also google but did not find any suitable way. If it is possible showing this data another way without using datagridview but the result is the way I have showed, that will also solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly what is the point to displaying like that since in database second row will have values of `V` and `Data 1`.

What could you do is on user click to add row, it check if database have same parameters in some cells (in your case first and second) and if it does then do not add new row but change current and in other cells add new values besides old ones.

If you do it like this then your `dataGridView` will display it like one row

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| V   |      Data 1      | Data 1 Quantity   | Data 1 Details   | //when editing existing cell value add new line so it displays like this
|     |                  | Data 1.A Quantity | Data 1.A Details |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Two other things you could do is:

- Create custom control that inherits from `DataGridView` class and inside it create function that will automatically merge cells with some condition and display it however you like (advenced level)
- Create extension method for `DataGridView` that will delete data of some cells on some condition

Example of the second solution is like this:

```
public static void EmptyOnDuplicateData(this DataGridView dgv, string columnToEmpty)
{
    List<string> ExistingData = new List<string>(); //I would do this with T and instead of passing string i would pass DataGridViewColumn so i could get type and other things but that is on you and i am just writing example

    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
    {
        if(ExistingData.Contains(row.Cells[columnToEmpty].Value)) //Data from this cell already existed before this cell
        {
            row.Cells[columnToEmpty].Value == ""; //We clear that from that cell
        }
        else // Data from this cell doesn't exist anywhere before
        {
            ExistingData.Add(row.Cells[columnToEmpty].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

And you just call it after populating your `DataGridView` with `yourDgv.EmptyOnDuplicateData("SomeColumn");`

I want to mention that code above is just example and it has a lot of not good things but just as i said, it is just example and i do not want to write code for you so you have base and just improve it.